# Running a copy of docker container

Tags: docker

Suppose I have a case when I need to rollback changes in my container, but I have only its name.

How can I achieve that with modern docker engine (currently 17.03.0-ce)?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily resolve the `id` of the container like:

```
#Bash (Linux/Mac)
containerId=`docker inspect -f"{{.Id}}" metrics_dashboard_1`

#PowerShell (windows)
$ContainerId = docker inspect -f"{{.Id}}" metrics_dashboard_1
```

Using this logic you should then be able to rollback/view your history for that container.

```
#Bash / PowerShell
docker tag $containerId $tagId
```

Comment: Can you please describe the way to do this?
Suppose I can commit current changes.
Then run my modifications.
How would I roll back to the previous state of the container? Before commit happens.

Comment: Can you include an example (_in code_) of how you are currently doing it, so I can amend it to match this example

Comment: I have a running container with its internal FS state (no volumes) it has some unknown running options (ports, hosts - an API of the container).
I should save its state (mark or store or duplicate).
Let the API of the container run MY JOB.
And then rollback it to the previous state.
The problem is that in a middle of that i don't know what exactly I should do.

Comment: Currently, I think that it should be like that.
1. Commit state of a running container to a tagged image.
2. Inspect all running options of the container.
3. Stop container.
4. Run a new container with gathered options based on the commited image.
5. do the stuff
6. stop container from p4.
7. run origin container.

But I am not sure about the way. Pretty long for me.

Comment: Docker does not keep "history" of a container. If you start a container, it mounts the image as read-only, and creates a "writable" layer on top of that. Any change you make in the container is stored in that writable layer. You can _commit_ the container to a new image, and start a new container from that to create a "snapshot". It's also possible to use (e.g.) the ZFS or BTRFS graph driver to take snapshots, but that's outside of docker itself